# Utilizar librería Interop sin tener el Office instalado

Tags: vb.net, interop

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en VB.NET (VS2015 + .NET4.5) y tengo que crear una serie de documentos Word con información que tengo en BBDD.

El problema es que esta aplicación será usada por gente que puede que no tenga instalado Word en su máquina. Entonces mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna solución?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, si alguna de las respuesta ayudo en la solucion de su problema puede que quiera votar +1 y/o aceptarla. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Recomendaria que en este caso que planteas no uses las librerias COM de office, ya que como bien estas mencionando requieres tener office instalado para poder usarlas

Como alternativa usa librerias basadas en `opem xml`.

Para `Word` usarias compoentes como ser

[DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/)

[Free .NET Word API](http://freeword.codeplex.com/)

Para `Excel` usarias

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

[SpreadSheetLigth](http://spreadsheetlight.com/)

Con esto te evitas depender de office en la pc del usuario.

Comment: Creo que voy a ir a algo más "primitivo". Voy a ir metiendo la información en un RichTextBox y luego haré un .SaveFile()

Comment: ok es bastante mas basico pero si te resulta util generar un .rtf entonces esta bien